# Resize blob Image from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, blob

Here's my code. I only got the width and height of the blob.

```
<?php while($get_lastest_pics = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_5_latest_ads_query_string_execute)){ 

    $im = imagecreatefromstring($get_lastest_pics['img']);
    $width = imagesx($im);
    $height = imagesy($im);
?>

<div class = "col-xs-3">
    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($get_lastest_pics['img']); ?>" class="latest_images img-responsive img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre" >    
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

What I want is to resize the images displayed there.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $tmpImage = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "some_prefix");
    $scaledIm = imagescale($im, 100, 100);

    imagejpeg($scaledIm, $tmpImage);
?>
    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode(file_get_contents($tmpImage)); ?>">
<?php
    unlink($tmpImage);
?>
```

Although I really, really hope this is not going to be your production code.
Just sore the path to the image in your DB and store the original image on the drive. Then scale it and serve the browser already scaled image. Just don't do this on the fly.

Comment: Yeah me too sir.. it's my first time seeing picture saved in the db which is i've heard not good... the company that i'm working for is trying to remake the design of their site.. I suggested to optimized everything but they won't let me since I'm new here... I got no choice..